# get all the exception within specific time range with help of awk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am very new to `awk` and was struggling to find out all the exception within specific time range.

Below is the logs,

`[2014-01-26 00:16:54.244][VendorProductFileProcessor-process-1][WARN]    [VendorProductFileTranslatorTask:210] Failed to process vendor data: {INTERNALCASHBACKSNAPDEALSPONSOREDPERCENTAGE=#REF!, VENDOR CODE=#REF!, INTERNALCASHBACKENDDATE=#REF!, INTERNALCASHBACKTYPEVALUE=#REF!, EXTERNALCASHBACKSTARTDATE=#REF!, SKU=#REF!, EXTERNALCASHBACKTYPEVALUE=#REF!, EXTERNALCASHBACKENDDATE=#REF!, EXTERNALCASHBACKTYPE=#REF!, EXTERNALCASHBACKSNAPDEALSPONSOREDPERCENTAGE=#REF!, INTERNALCASHBACKSTARTDATE=#REF!, INTERNALCASHBACKTYPE=#REF!}, com.snapdeal.coms.exception.RuntimeErrorException: COMS-1113: Failed to translate attribute : intCashbackTotalValue value: Unparseable number: "#REF!"`

Now I am trying to print all the Exception occurred in last 1 hour. I am using below `awk` command

`grep Exception coms-core.log | gawk -F '[' '{ if ($2 ~ \2014-01-26 00:[0-59]:[0-59]\)print $2}'`

But I am getting exception while executing it

```
gawk: { if ($2 ~ \2014-01-26 00:[0-59]:[0-59]\)print $2}
gawk:            ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Can someone help me out here?

Using below awk script with the help of anubhava's answer,but when i am trying to use minutes range as regex, it is now working.

grep Exception coms-core.log | head -1 | gawk -F '[' ' $2 ~ /^2014-01-26 [00]:[0-59]/ {print $2}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
gawk -F '[' '$0 ~ /Exception/ && $2 ~ /^2014-01-26 16:/ {print $2}' coms-core.log
```

- You don't need grep since awk can handle that part as well
- Your awk syntax wasn't correct

Comment: 1 small doubt
[readlog@coms01 coms-core]$ grep Exception coms-core.log | head -1 | gawk -F '[' ' $2 ~ /^2014-01-26 [00:01]/ {print $2}'
2014-01-26 00:16:54.244]
but when i am trying to give range of minutes too with regex 
grep Exception coms-core.log | head -1 | gawk -F '[' ' $2 ~ /^2014-01-26 [00]:[0-59]/ {print $2}'

I am not getting any result. any hint what am i doing wrong

Comment: Actually your regex is wrong in giving minute range. Remember its not numeric range it is regex range. Your code is difficult to read from comments, if you post your code in your question then I can certainly suggest you a fix.

Comment: You can just use `$2 ~ /^2014-01-26 00:/` and don't need to specify `00-59` minute range since we only want logs of a particular hour.

Comment: yes, actually i want to get the count of total exception against every minute .

Comment: Then you need: `$2 ~ /^2014-01-26 00:(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])/` for matching `00:00` - `00:59`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are denoted with a forward slash (`/expr/`).

Comment: after using forward slesh i am getting below exception
[readlog@coms01 coms-core]$ grep Exception coms-core.log | head -1 | gawk -F '[' '{ if ($2 ~ '/2014-01-26 00:[0-59]:[0-59]/') print $2}'
gawk: { if ($2 ~ /2014-01-26
gawk:             ^ unterminated regexp
gawk: cmd. line:1: { if ($2 ~ /2014-01-26
gawk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: what's the `'` doing there?

Comment: I was doing stupid mistake. thanks karloy for helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

To find out exception in last 1 hour using find command -

find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -name 'coms-core.log' -exec grep -wi 'exceptions' {} \; 2>/dev/null